# Jenkins Failing on 'git pull'

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, jenkins, gitlab

I set up a subdomain on my DO droplet which is running Jenkins.

I want Jenkins to deploy my project when a new build is pushed to my GitLab master branch.

The problem is that I am getting a `git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey)` error.

The issue is that when running `git pull` on my ubuntu droplet, everything is working perfectly, so my ssh keys should be working fine.  But when executing a shell on **BUILD**, I am running into this error.

I also have to run `sudo git pull` or I am getting a `cannot open .git/fetch_head permission denied` error.  Again when running all of these commands on my DO ubuntu droplet.

Am I supposed to set up another SSH key on the Jenkins GUI?

EDIT:
I am using user jenkins, which is default Jenkins user.

Answer (score 1):

When you are manually running `git pull` on the droplet, are you running as the same user as Jenkins? You might need to add the ssh key for a different user. I believe by default, Jenkins runs under a `jenkins` user.

Comment: you are correct.  But I am also using user Jenkins when running on my Ubuntu server.

Comment: Have you looked at your /etc/ssh/sshd_config? You might need to update PermitRootLogin to yes and PasswordAuthentication to yes and reload the ssh service with `sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: But that will open up some security risks, won't it?